# I have this small PL/SQL code but I want to modify it to include reservation start and end Date

Tags: oracle, plsql

My goal here is to change the reservation room type if there is availability for that room type during the reservation’s date interval and I'm unsure how to go about implementing the interval check. Here is what I currently have...

```
create or replace procedure ChangeRoomTypetest(curr_res_id number,curr_room_type varchar2,res_start date,res_end date)
is 
begin
if(Reserve_Date >= res_start and reserve_end_date <= res_end)
then
update reservation
set room_types = curr_room_type
where curr_res_id = reserve_id;

else
    dbms_output.putline('All rooms reserved');
end if;
end;
```

Here is the table I am working with

[image]

Comment: you need to check if a room is existing for the data range and the room type and if existing then you should be updating the curr_res_id  with the new room type. In your current code i don't see.

Comment: "if(Reserve_Date >= res_start and reserve_end_date <= res_end)"  You are treating these like variables, but it appears they are actually columns in your table.  Either way, you are comparing them to procedure input parms without ever actually populating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you need to check the overlaps as follows:

```
create or replace procedure ChangeRoomTypetest(curr_res_id number,curr_room_type varchar2,res_start date,res_end date)
is 
begin

update reservation
set room_types = curr_room_type
where curr_res_id = reserve_id 
And not (reserve_date between res_start and res_end
         or res_start between reserve_date and reserve_end_date)

If sql%rowcount = 0 then
    dbms_output.putline('All rooms reserved');
end if;
end;
```